# Successfully activated Administrator user on Windows 10 Home, but still asks me permission from administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, fonts, administrator

Now I'm completely fazed.

I don't understand why Windows 10 is complaining about administrator permissions.

A while ago I was annoyed about how this fonts folder could not be deleted, asking permissions. So naturally I found about how Windows 10 (Home ed) was hindering me from making any changes to my computer, and I activated the hidden administrator user. That was yesterday.

And shazam, the fonts folder won't let itself be deleted. With this very administrator account I remember myself being able to hold success in seeking its bane, and now it's lingering to my computer like some virus.

Win 10 Home, ver. 1511.

[image: The screenshot. Not giving me anything to work my way out. No More Details, no errorcodes, no nothing.]

Comment: Try to run Explorer as admin.

Comment: [apply my hack](https://superuser.com/a/1060578/174557) to be able to run Explorer as admin.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to delete the Fonts folder?

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the ownership of the folder that you want to delete?
Right click on the folder>properties> then click the "security" tab> click on "advanced" near the bottom> click on the "owner" tab> then click"edit"... you will now see who owns the folder... > click on the administrator account that you are using and want to use for full control and remember to highlight the "Replace Owner on Subcontainers and objects" box>click "apply"> click "ok"> and a pop up asks if you want to replace the permissions folder with a new permissions folder containing you full control, click yes.
you may have to turn off "inheriting permissions". You could check the link below. It describes a similar issue with you.
[Can't delete folder and I am admin. "You need permission to perform this action. You require permission from..."](https://superuser.com/questions/204909/cant-delete-folder-and-i-am-admin-you-need-permission-to-perform-this-action)

Comment: Thanks, err... but none of the methods are working. handle returns nothing, icacls I already tried... Thanks anyway.